# Invalid date when I put a future timestamp

Tags: javascript, date

Suppose to have a future timestamp date.

```
var timestamp="1511858535000" //Future timestamp
var date=new Date(timestamp);
console.log(JSON.stringify(date));// this line give me Invalid Data
```

Anyone can help me to understand why?

Comment: What "Future timestamp" are you using? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: @dferenc for example this timestamp "1511858535000" is Tuesday, 28 November 2017 08:42:15. when I put this timestamp in var date=new Date(timestamp) it gives me "Invalid date"

Comment: That is an invalid timestamp for `new Date();`.

Comment: @dferenc why is an invalid timestamp? because is a future timestamp?

Comment: For future reference, it would be best if you provided complete code that demonstrates the problem (e.g. include the timestamp in the question instead of `.... //Future timestamp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timestamp you mentioned in the comments works fine, but you have to pass it into the Date constructor as a number, not a string:

```js
var timestamp = "1511858535000";
var date = new Date(Number(timestamp));
console.log(JSON.stringify(date));
```